# Обновление бд в visual studio

Tags: c#, winforms, access

Добавил новый столбец в таблицу в access, но visual studio видит таблицу без нового столбца. То есть, есть таблица с Имя, Фамилия, Отчество. Добавил в access столбец Телефон. Но в visual studio всё так же Имя, Фамилия, Отчество. Подскажите как обновить бд в visual studio.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, каким ORM Вы пользуетесь для работы с таблицей Access в Visual Studio? Это DataSet или Entity Framewrok, или, может, какой-нибудь сторонний инструмент?

Comment: Уже не актуально)